# Adding a UIButton to AdWhirl ad banner

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, adwhirl

How to add a UIButton to AdWhirl ad banner? Trivial `[adWhirlView addSubview: button]` doesn't work. Button doesn't appear.

**UPD** Already tried:

```
[view addSubview:adWhirlView];
[adWhirlView addSubview:button];
[adWhirlView bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

adWhirlView is visible, but not the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try to add the button and AdWhirl view to the same parent view? Something like this:

```
[view addSubview: adWhirlView];
[view addSubview: button];
```

It will be same view hierarchy you pursue, in my opinion. You will only need to position the button the way you want.

**UPD:**
If the AdWhirl fails to receive ads, it fires the delegate method:

```
-(void)adWhirlDidFailToReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView usingBackup:(BOOL)yesOrNo
```

So you can toggle the visibility of your button using AdWhirl didReceive/didFail methods. Start with adding a hidden button, then on didReceive: set

```
button.hidden = NO;
```

and on didFail:

```
button.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: I did it this way, and it worked, but there was a problem: when ads unavailale for some reason (no internet) button hovers over screen. It looks odd when button appear without ad.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  [adWhirlView bringSubviewToFront:button];
```